# Workflow rule to create Task not working - help?

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a Workflow rule that fires upon the creation of a Case when it meets a certain field criterion.  It is set up to both send an email to a support rep, and also create a Task for her at the same time.  The email notification is working fine, but the Tasks are not being created.  Is there any reason why one workflow action would be happening but not the other?

Here is the setup of the workflow rule:
[image]

And here is the Task Workflow Action:
[image]

Comment: The task will be assigned to the user in the Assigned To: If that is not happening, open up the dev console with workflow rule processing set to finest and see what is happening.

Comment: Trigger with caught/uncaught exceptions or validation rules on the Task?

Comment: So I dug in a bit deeper and discovered that the tasks are being created and attached to the Case.  For some reason they were not coming up in our report trying to find them, and we were looking for them to be related to the Case's Account, not the Case.